# How does the GoPro pair with an iPhone?

Tags: ios, p2p, live-streaming, wifi-direct, gopro

I am trying to build an iOS application which is able to receive a live data stream from a camera and displaying the stream on the screen. The connection between the camera and the device (iPad/iPhone) should be P2P, like the GoPro connects to the iPhone. Meaning the camera should open up a Wlan and the iPhone should be able to connect to it. My first question is how this technique is called to do further research. The second one is can this be achieved with a raspberry pi (with camera module and wifi dongle) or any other microcontroller.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello @riik , have you found any leads on this so far ?

Comment: by the way you may do this too :  cam  ---- ( wifi ) -->  web app  -----( webrtc )----> client app